# adk.test: sample size

Tags: r, anderson-darling-test

I'm using the function `adk.test` ([AD test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test), [adk package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adk/adk.pdf)) to estimate if a data sample follows a distribution family.

My question is I have `data`with 100 values, should I simulate the distribution with 100 values or with as many as I want? `rnorm(100)` or `rnorm(1000000)`

EDIT:
using `fitdist` and `gofstat` functions of `fitdistrplus` package I get the following results:

Ex: `Normal distribution`

```
ad = 1.4491191816923, 
adtest = "rejected"
```

How can I check the validity of the function conclusion? I must compare `ad` with....

Also for the same `data` I get very different conclusions using `adk`:

```
1st quartile of 100 runs of `adk` with 1000 samples:
p-value = 0.20
min p-value = 0.05
conclusion: the null cannot be rejected
```

Comment: The AD test can be applied for testing if a sample comes from a certain distribution $F$ or if several samples come from the same distribution but it appears to me that the former is not available in this package. You could simulate from the distribution $F$ and compare it with the data using `adk.test(data,simulations)` but it is not clear the required number of simulations for obtaining meaningful results (I guess that as many as possible but I would not bet on this). Are you interested on testing normallity?

Comment: That's also my guess, but this is an important choice that's why I posted :)

Comment: If it is important, then why not implement the single-sample AD test? The test statistic is not extremely difficult and then you do not have to worry about the sample size.

Comment: Do you mean creating the function? `adk` is available and I'd like to see if it works. Only if I have evidence that it does not work will I think of developing the test myself.

Comment: I'm interested in testing normality and other distributions.

Comment: I do think the question has improved, in that it more clearly reflects your situation & what you need to know, however, I note that the question now revolves, in large part, around how / why 2 R functions appear to give differing results. We can see how this Q fares in its current incarnation, but if you don't get a satisfactory answer it may do better on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), or probably even as a submission to the R help listserv.

Answer (score 2):

Following on @Procrastinator's astute [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35247/adk-test-sample-size#comment70512_35247), it may be that [?adk.test](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=adk:adk.test) is not the optimal function for you to be using here.  The [fitdistrplus package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/index.html) offers a number of functions that will better serve your goals of determining which distribution is best.  You should read its [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/vignettes/intro2fitdistrplus.pdf).  You can get the A-D test (as well as Kolmogorov-Smirnov, and Cramer-Von Mises) via:

```
fit = fitdist(x, "<some_dist_type>")
gofstat(fit, print.test=T)
```

Comment: Thanks! I already tried that function but since it does not return information that allows me to understand how the function achieves the conclusions about the rejecting or not rejecting the null I don't trust it and tried adk instead. It gives me different results and more coherent to what I was expecting.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to ask about that. Can you say more about what you need to know to understand / trust it?